# Fetching data from three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have the following three tables:

```
zone (id, zonename, zoneaddr, modified)
sector (id, zoneid, sectorname, sectoraddr, modified)
beat (id, sectorid, beatname, beataddr, modified)
```

In another table (employee), the id's of all above three tables are saved against the data of an employee.

When I fetch a record from employee, I get the id's of all three tables and I want to fetch zonename, sectorname and beatname in one query from the above tables if zone.id, sector.id and beat.id are already known

Comment: Please include your SQL code.

Comment: Please use or search about join in sql. And if you have done some query then please share it also.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per question 
You have shown 4 tables in Total

- Employee
- Zone
- Sector
- Beat

so in Employee table you have zoneID, secotrID, beatID.

Then what are you waiting for...

Hit this query and you will get what you want

```
Select e.*, z.zoneName, s.sectorName, b.beatName From employee e INNER JOIN Zone z ON e.zoneID = z.id INNER JOIN sector s ON e.sectorID = s.id INNER JOIN Beat b ON e.beatID = b.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Bhuvnesh: I am fetching a row from table_employee through the following statement:  "SELECT * FROM employee  where cnic = '".$parameter."' OR name LIKE '%".$parameter."%' LIMIT ?, ?";                                                                      Now the query fetches all data when match hits and it fetches the zone, sector and beat id from employee whereas zonename, sectorname and beatname are required which are defined in table_zone, Table_sector and Table_beat. Kindly construct a query so that i get the other fields including the zone, sector and beat name instead of their id's

Comment: Can you please provide what are only required columns from employee table that you want fetch instead of all?

Comment: all columns from employee table and want to display the zone, sector and beat names along with other column data instead of their id's. Now employees table stores zone, sector and beats id's. so i just want that when I fetch a record it should have the names of these three fields instead of their id's.

Comment: so you simply want to exclude zoneID, beatID, sectorID from employee table,

Then try query something like this,

`Select e.name, e.cnic, e.email, z.zoneName, s.sectorName, b.beatName From employee e INNER JOIN Zone z ON e.zoneID = z.id INNER JOIN sector s ON e.sectorID = s.id INNER JOIN Beat b ON e.beatID = b.id;`

Comment: $query = "select e.* , z.zonename, s.sectorname, b.beatname from " . $this->table_emp . " e
left join zones z
on z.id = e.postingZone
left join sectors s
on s.id = e.postingSector
left join beats b
on b.id = e.postingBeat where 
   cnic = '".$parameter."'
   OR name LIKE '%".$parameter."%' 
   LIMIT ?, ?";                                                                                           It still fetching the id's not the names from other tables

Comment: same result on this query $query = "Select e.*, z.zonename, s.sectorname, b.beatname From " . $this->table_emp . " e INNER JOIN zones z ON e.postingZone = z.id INNER JOIN sectors s ON e.postingSector = s.id INNER JOIN beats b ON e.postingBeat = b.id where 
   cnic = '".$parameter."'
   OR name LIKE '%".$parameter."%' 
   LIMIT ?, ?";

Comment: you have used e.*, so it will fetch ids from employee table, All you need to check if these ids are present in other tables too and if the columns are correct, if everything is fine then zonename, beatbane, sectorname must be at the end of the data, please check it out and if still facing the issue then post the result along with the query used.

Comment: the query now fetches only those record where values/id's for e.postingZone, e.postingSector and e.postingBeat exists. but it still fetching the id's, not the names from other tables

Comment: it is obvious that employees who have zoneids that dont exist in zones table then how can it show zonename, but still you want to show all employees whether ids are present then use left join instead of Inner join

Comment: After lots of effort if the answer is working fine then please accept the answer and appreciate him. @SKYz

Answer (score 1):

Try like ths.

For getting zonename, sectorname and beatname along with employee details

```
select e.* , z.zonename, s.sectorname, b.beatname from employee e
left join zone z
on z.id = e.id
left join sector s
on s.id = e.id
left join beat b
on b.id = e.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select em.*, zo.zoneName, se.sectorName, be.beatName 
    From
    employee em 
    INNER JOIN Zone zo 
        ON em.zoneID = zo.id 
    INNER JOIN sector se 
        ON em.sectorID = se.id 
    INNER JOIN Beat be 
        ON em.beatID = be.id;
```

Comment: the previous query already worked and thanks again.. stay blessed